# Java doesn't see fatjar dependencies

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, minecraft

So on my adventure to learn programming I decided to make quite a simple Minecraft mod, which would add Discord Rich Presence integration. Unfortunately this requires me to use a 3rd party lib: discord-rpc. Now, Minecraft can't load load .jars unless they are mods, so I built my mod into a fatjar (dependecies come packaged with the jar). Now instead of:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/arikia/dev/drpc/DiscordRPC`
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.arikia.dev.drpc.DiscordRPC`
...I get:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/SystemUtils
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils`
The solution seems to be simple: package the Apache Commons Lang dependency with the jar... until you realize that discord-rpc comes with the Lang packaged inside it. And inside my fatjar: SystemUtils.class is exactly where it needs to be - at org/apache/commons/lang/.
I don't have a clue what's going on. I've already asked my friend who's much better at programming than me and he doesn't have a clue either.
[Fatjar in question](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dl9avtqp8k83c5/richmc-1.0-all.jar?dl=1)
[All the code](https://github.com/maak4422/RichMC), if for some reason you need it or want to look at it.

Comment: You should be Defining the jar as a maven dependency in your dependencies block.

Comment: Minecraft already comes with the apache libraries, so there's no need to bundle them. Minecraft modding does not support natives out of the box. Find a different discord library, there's plenty.

Comment: Consider using this pure java impl. https://github.com/PSNRigner/discord-rpc-java